# How to change size of the tooltip of @Html.TextAreaFor in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tooltip

How to change size of the tooltip of `@Html.TextAreaFor` in MVC 4

Hi

I have a TextArea with lengthy text, When hovering over it with lengthy text the entire text should display in tooltip.

This is My code :

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Ref_InsuranceComment.Comment1, new { modalTitle = "Insurance Comments"})
```

the Request is:
Change hover feature so that when user hovers over the comments field, the entire contents of the comments field are displayed.

I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding some jQuery cods :

adding jQuery tooltip to textarea

```
.tooltip
{
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 1px;
    border: 1px solid #0066CC;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 500px;
}

var showTooltip = function (event) {
    $('div.tooltip').remove();
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        var content = $(this).val();
        content = content.replace(/\n/g, '<BR>');
        $('<div Id="hiddenDiv" class="tooltip">   ' + content + '<BR class=lbr>' + '</div>').appendTo('body');
        changeTooltipPosition(event);
    }
};

var changeTooltipPosition = function (event) {
    var tooltipX = event.pageX - 8;
    var tooltipY = event.pageY + 8;
    $('div.tooltip').css({ top: tooltipY, left: tooltipX });
};

var hideTooltip = function () {
    $('div.tooltip').remove();
};

$("textarea").bind({
    mousemove: changeTooltipPosition,
    mouseenter: showTooltip,
    mouseleave: hideTooltip
});
```